# C# Split a file into two byte arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, file, byte

Because the maximum value of a byte array is 2GB, lets say i have a larger file and i need to convert it to a byte array. Since i can't hold the whole file, how should i convert it into two?

I tried:

```
long length = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"c:\a.mp4").Length;
int chunkSize = Convert.ToInt32(length / 2); 


byte[] part2;
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
try
{
    part2 = new byte[chunkSize];            // create buffer
    fileStream.Read(part2, 0, chunkSize);
}
finally
{
    fileStream.Close();
}

byte[] part3;
fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
try
{
    part3 = new byte[chunkSize];            // create buffer
    fileStream.Read(part3, 5, (int)(length - (long)chunkSize));
}
finally
{
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

but it's not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/file-is-too-large-to-read-into-a-byte-array)

Comment: do you need to hold entire file in memory ?

Comment: When you need to do something with a large file you should find an approach that doesn't try to read the entire file into memory if you can help it.

Comment: @Tigran I can't think of another option..

Comment: @AaYy Well what do you plain to do with those byte arrays after you have them in memory?  There might be an approach that doesn't require the entire file in memory.  Chunking it up like that would break any valid reason anyway.  This is basically a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @AaYy: there are always trade offs involved in these kind of situations. So I would suggest to look into [Memory Mapped Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
byte[] part1;
byte[] part2;
bool odd = false;
int chunkSize = Convert.ToInt32(length/2);


if (length % 2 == 0)
{
    part1 = new byte[chunkSize];
    part2 = new byte[chunkSize];
}
else
{
    part1 = new byte[chunkSize];
    part2 = new byte[chunkSize + 1];
    odd = true;
}

FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using (fileStream)
{
    fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(part1, 0, chunkSize);
    if (odd)
    {
        bytesRead = fileStream.Read(part2, 0, chunkSize + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        bytesRead = fileStream.Read(part2, 0, chunkSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your offset always 0? FortyTwo has a more generic and better solution. Re-usability and abstraction should be kept in mind while programming with an OOP language.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `StreamReader` to read in [file too large to read into a byte array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/file-is-too-large-to-read-into-a-byte-array)

```
const int max = 1024*1024;

public void ReadALargeFile(string file, int start = 0)
{
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    using (fileStream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[max];
        fileStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, start, max);
        while(bytesRead > 0)
        {
            DoSomething(buffer, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, start, max);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the array that holds my data? is it buffer?

Comment: `buffer` holds data between `start` and `start + max - 1`. Documentation for [FileStream.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with extremely large files, you should use [`MemoryMappedFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx), which maps a physical file to a memory space:

```
using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"c:\path\to\big.file"))
{
    using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
    {
        byte myValue = accessor.ReadByte(someOffset);
        accessor.Write((byte)someValue);
    }
}
```

See also: [`MemoryMappedViewAccessor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can also read/write chunks of the file with the different methods in `MemoryMappedViewAccessor`.